# Как заставить WCF не подменять SecurityException

Tags: c#, wcf

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Если я на сервере, внутри метода службы бросаю SecurityException с сообщением, которое хочу отобразить пользователю на клиенте, это исключение заменяется на FaultException с сообщением "Отказано в доступе". Причём в таком виде оно доходит не только до клиента, но уже до реализации `IErrorHandler`, подсунутой хосту.

Если бросить не SecurityException, а его наследника - результат тот же самый.

Понятно, что можно бросать другой тип исключения, объявленный в контракте сбоев, но если по семантике это SecurityException, такое решение не вполне корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы объект  типа SecurityException пробрасывался на сторону клиента его нужно прописать в интерфейсе контракта при помощи атрибута [FaultContractAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.servicemodel.faultcontractattribute.aspx)

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceContract
{
   [OperationContract]
   [FaultContractAttribute(typeof(SecurityException))]
   void CallMethod();
}
```